# After upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 I cant use my mapped folders from either windows 10 or mac OSX Mojave

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

Error message mac is server may not exist or it is unavailable, windows cannot access "server". I can ssh into the server from both windows and mac. Not sure what could be the problem as both worked fine under 16.04. I am a newbie using Linux. I did have to reinstall linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic before I could upgrade.